# Azure DevOps & Azure CLI: Unable to locate executable file

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-cli, azure-pipelines-yaml

When trying to run a simple Azure CLI Task in my ubuntu-based Azure DevOps pipeline I get the following error message:

```
##[error]Script failed with error: Error: Unable to locate executable file: 
'/home/vsts/work/_temp/azureclitaskscript1637831708745.bat'. 
Please verify either the file path exists or the file can be found within a directory specified by the PATH environment variable. 
Also check the file mode to verify the file is executable.
```

If I'm reading this correctly the inline script is not being found, right? What am I missing here? Here's the full YAML:

```
trigger:
- main
- dev

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: AzureCLI@2
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'My Subscription Name'
    scriptType: 'batch'
    scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
    inlineScript: 'az --version'
```

Comment: A `batch` file on Ubuntu... that won't really work. Try setting it to `bash`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're running your task on Linux, you can't use `batch` there, you'll need to pick `pscore` or `bash` instead, or switch to a `windows-latest` vmImage.

> Script Type*: Select the type of script to be executed on the agent. Task supports four types: Batch / Shell / PowerShell / PowerShell Core scripts, default selection being empty. Select Shell/PowerShell Core script when running on Linux agent or Batch/PowerShell/PowerShell Core script when running on Windows agent. PowerShell Core script can run on cross-platform agents (Linux, macOS, or Windows)

<sup>https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/tree/master/Tasks/AzureCLIV2#parameters-of-the-task</sup>

The actual [strings to pass to the arguments can be found in the task.json](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/AzureCLIV2/task.json#L57-L60). It looks like the task doesn't do any validation on these fields, causing this weird error situation.

```
            "options": {
                "ps": "PowerShell",
                "pscore": "PowerShell Core",
                "batch": "Batch",
                "bash": "Shell"
            }
```

Comment: just noticed it, wrote batch instead of bash 

Comment: They could really improve on the error message here...